# new NioDatagramChannelFactory fails when jacoco is enabled

Tags: java, ant, junit, netty, jacoco

I have some junit test cases where I create `DatagramChannelFactory` for every test case. When I run these test cases normally, I do not have any problem instantiating `NioDatagramChannelFactory` .

```
DatagramChannelFactory channelFactory = new NioDatagramChannelFactory(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10));
```

But when I enable `jacoco` for the same piece of code, the instantiate fails. My `jacoco` is integrated with  ant and the part of build.xml concerned looks like this :

Since jacoco requires `fork="yes"` attribute I'm adding the same.

```
<jacoco:coverage>
  <junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="no" showoutput="yes" fork="yes" >
    blah.. blah.. 
    <batchtest fork="true" todir="${reportsUTrawdir}">
       blah.. blah.. 
    </batchtest>
 </junit>
</jacoco:coverage>
```

and my junit target looks like below :

```
<junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="no" showoutput="yes">
  <formatter type="xml" />

  <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${reportsUTrawdir}">
    blah.. blah.. 
  </batchtest>
</junit>
```

The stack trace I get is :

```
Failed to create a selector.

org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to create a selector.
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.openSelector(AbstractNioSelector.java:343)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.<init>(AbstractNioSelector.java:100)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.<init>(AbstractNioSelector.java:95)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.<init>(AbstractNioWorker.java:48)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioDatagramWorker.<init>(NioDatagramWorker.java:54)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioDatagramWorkerPool.createWorker(NioDatagramWorkerPool.java:35)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioDatagramWorkerPool.createWorker(NioDatagramWorkerPool.java:26)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorkerPool.newWorker(AbstractNioWorkerPool.java:143)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorkerPool.init(AbstractNioWorkerPool.java:81)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorkerPool.<init>(AbstractNioWorkerPool.java:69)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorkerPool.<init>(AbstractNioWorkerPool.java:55)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioDatagramWorkerPool.<init>(NioDatagramWorkerPool.java:29)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioDatagramChannelFactory.<init>(NioDatagramChannelFactory.java:140)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioDatagramChannelFactory.<init>(NioDatagramChannelFactory.java:124)
```

Is there anything I'm missing when I'm tearing down my test case. Please help me through.

EDIT : Added the cause I got from junit report :

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection
at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:106)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl.<init>(PipeImpl.java:122)
at sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openPipe(SelectorProviderImpl.java:27)
at java.nio.channels.Pipe.open(Pipe.java:133)
at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.<init>(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:105)
at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorProvider.openSelector(WindowsSelectorProvider.java:26)
at java.nio.channels.Selector.open(Selector.java:209)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.SelectorUtil.open(SelectorUtil.java:63)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.openSelector(AbstractNioSelector.java:341)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:507)
at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(SocketChannel.java:146)
at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:78)
```

Comment: Does the `ChannelException` have a cause? Could you also provide the stack trace of the cause?

Comment: @trustin: Please find my edit

Comment: Is there any security manager in action? To me, it looks like something is preventing from opening a new selector.  In Windows, to open a Selector, a loopback connection (a pipe more precisely) must be created.

Comment: @trustin : I disabled firewall, even after which I'm getting this error. Since I can run test cases without errors when I run as normal junit tests. But when I enable jacoco(code coverage library), I'm getting this error. So, I'm doubting jacoco as the culprit. I'm trying to find out the same. Do let me know if u find anything fishy with jacoco.

Comment: We run jacoco coverage test periodically on our CI machine and we see no such problem.  However, the CI machine is Linux.  I'd like to advise you to talk to the Jacoco folks just in case it's a bug in Jacoco.